# Twilio Invalid 'StatusCallbackEvent' Error - 21626

Tags: twilio

```
One or more of the StatusCallbackEvents provided were invalid.

invalidStatusCallbackEvents "canceled no-answer busy failed"
```

I removed those 4 events from above since they do not seem to ever be valid according to:

- https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132267-Tracking-the-call-status-of-an-outbound-call
- the invalid callback events are actually finalized call statuses: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132547-What-are-the-Possible-Call-Statuses-and-What-do-They-Mean-

Is this the correct way to fix the issue? Or are those 4 StatusCallbackEvents valid under some context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You're correct, none of those are events, they are statuses. In fact, they are all statuses that could be sent as part of the "completed" event.

The call events you can register for callbacks for are: [`initiated`, `ringing`, `answered` and `completed`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call#statuscallbackevent).

Comment: How do i get the info about the termination state while receiving the completed event?

Comment: @ThomasMeinhart You need to check the [`CallStatus` or `DialCallStatus` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#callstatus-values) that is sent to the webhook URL.

Comment: thank you. I just received "completed" status until i recognized that if the mailbox starts running it is also "answering" my phone call. Now i'm using a shorter timeout duration to avoid landing in the mailbox. So i get the "no-answer" status.

Comment: Ah, of course. You might want to check answering machine detection too: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection

Comment: I have already come across this, but due to the costs we will not use it for the time being.